# "Maximum number of parameters" error with filter .in_(list) using pyodbc

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

One of our queries that was working in Python 2 + mxODBC is not working in Python 3 + pyodbc; it raises an error like this: `Maximum number of parameters in the sql query is 2100.` while connecting to SQL Server. Since both the printed queries have 3000 params, I thought it should fail in both environments, but clearly that doesn't seem to be the case here. In the Python 2 environment, both MSODBC 11 or MSODBC 17 works, so I immediately ruled out a driver related issue.

So my question is:

1. Is it correct to send a `list` as multiple params in SQLAlchemy because the param list will be proportional to the length of `list`? I think it looks a bit strange; I would have preferred concatenating the `list` into a single `string` because the DB doesn't understand the `list` datatype.
2. Are there any hints on why it would be working in mxODBC but not pyodbc? Does mxODBC optimize something that pyodbc does not? Please let me know if there are any pointers - I can try and paste more info here. (I am still new to debugging SQLAlchemy.)

Footnote: I have seen lot of answers that suggest to **chunk the data**, but because of **1 and 2**, I wonder if I am doing the correct thing in the first place.

(Since it seems to be related to pyodbc, I have raised an [internal issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/807) in the official repository.)

```
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.orm

from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from  sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

Base = declarative_base()

create_tables = """
CREATE TABLE products(
    idn NUMERIC(8) PRIMARY KEY
);
"""

check_tables = """   
SELECT * FROM products;
"""

insert_values = """
INSERT INTO products
(idn)
values
(1),
(2);
"""

delete_tables = """
DROP TABLE products;
"""

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@dsn')
connection = engine.connect()
cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=connection)
session = Session()

session.execute(create_tables)

metadata = MetaData(connection)

class Products(Base):
   __table__ = Table('products', metadata, autoload=True)

try:
    session.execute(check_tables)
    session.execute(insert_values)
    session.commit()
    query = session.query(Products).filter(
        Products.idn.in_(list(range(0, 3000)))
    )
    query.all()
    f = open("query.sql", "w")
    f.write(str(query))
    f.close()
finally:
    session.execute(delete_tables)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: `in_(list_of_values)` is ok - sqlalchemy handles constructing the SQL, quoting etc.  Are all the queries (python2 & 3, pyodbc & mxodbc) all being run against the same server?

Comment: Also, are the dsns using the same driver (not sure how would tell, I haven't worked with MSSQL for a long time).

Comment: What DBMS were you connecting to using mxODBC? The 2100 parameter limit is set by SQL Server.

Comment: @snakecharmerb It works fine in Python 2 environment with both MSODBC 11 and MSODBC 17 drivers. I switch it using the `Driver` property in `odbc.ini`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, Sorry forgot to mention that - it is MSSQL Server only. I updated that in my question.

Comment: I suppose that 2100 limit also stems from how PyODBC sends the query to SQL Server. It happens to be the limit of parameters to a SP. One solution around it would be to use a TVP, but PyODBC does not support them. You could also create a temporary table, upload the data to it, and select from it in the IN clause (or replace it with an INNER JOIN).

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yeah, that seems to be the only good explanation so far! Even I am suspecting PyODBC is doing something different - not sure if it is good or bad though; I will try to look up more on that. INNER JOIN seems to be a good lead ...

Comment: @IljaEverilä - pyodbc does support TVPs now, although there is at least one [limitation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/601).

Comment: @gordthompson Oh that's good news!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do a straightforward `.in_(list_of_values)` SQLAlchemy renders the following SQL ...

```sql
SELECT team.prov AS team_prov, team.city AS team_city 
FROM team 
WHERE team.prov IN (?, ?)
```

... where each value in the IN clause is specified as a separate parameter value. pyodbc sends this to SQL Server as ...

```sql
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(4),@P2 nvarchar(4)',N'SELECT team.prov AS team_prov, team.city AS team_city, team.team_name AS team_team_name 
FROM team 
WHERE team.prov IN (@P1, @P2)',N'AB',N'ON'
```

... so you hit the limit of 2100 parameters if your list is very long. Presumably, mxODBC inserted the parameter values inline before sending it to SQL Server, e.g.,

```sql
SELECT team.prov AS team_prov, team.city AS team_city 
FROM team 
WHERE team.prov IN ('AB', 'ON')
```

You can get SQLAlchemy to do that for you with

```py
provinces = ["AB", "ON"]
stmt = (
    session.query(Team)
    .filter(
        Team.prov.in_(sa.bindparam("p1", expanding=True, literal_execute=True))
    )
    .statement
)
result = list(session.query(Team).params(p1=provinces).from_statement(stmt))
```

Comment: Heh, my comment that SQLA constructed the query wasn't thought through - I should have realised it would delegate to the DB-API driver.  Good answer.

Comment: Expanding bindparam is the most useful thing I keep forgetting about all the time :/

Comment: Please note that this feature is only available in 1.4.x version of SQLAlchemy which is currently in beta and pending release.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me solve [a different problem](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/issues/620#issuecomment-1666861234) I had with psycopg (postgresql driver).

Comment: This is a great answer with a very unknown feature...thank you!